# Fancybox closing when post back occurs

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, fancybox

I have an asp.net app with a modal fancybox set up as an iframe.  I have a process where I am scanning a credit card and the fancybox goes away as soon as the scan takes place.  I can reproduce this by simply hitting the enter key. So, it appears a postback is causing the fancybox to close.

I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work.  Here is how the fancybox is orginlly loaded:

```
$.fancybox({
    'modal': true,
    'width': '100%',
    'height': 1300,
    'padding': 5,
    'autoScale': false,
    'transitionIn': 'elastic',
    'transitionOut': 'elastic',
    'type': 'iframe',
    'href': storeUrl,
    'title': 'Welcome to the Store',
    'titlePosition': 'over',
    'onStart': function ()
    {
        openSF();
    },
    'onClosed': function ()
    {
        closedSF();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try binding the form in the iframe to a jquery function to capture any posts that are happening. We use barcode scanners at work and each time one is scanned the characters are returned, plus a CRLF which submits the form. This could be happening with the credit card scanner.

```
$('#MyFormId').bind('submit', function () { 

    //Optional code to run after credit card scanned

    return false;   //Ensures form never actually "posts" - just stays on this page 
});
```

Comment: I tried adding the code above in the content block and it is not stopping the postback.  Is there anything else I need to do?